# Route to the new data submitted by Meteor autoform using iron router, Autoform.addHooks this.docId is null?

Tags: meteor, meteor-autoform

I'm an inexperienced Meteor developer. AutoForm.addHooks onSuccess returns this.docID as undefined and I don't understand why?

```
AutoForm.addHooks('AddQuoteDataForm', {
    onSuccess: function () {
        console.log("AutoForm.addHooks AddQuoteDataForm insert! - docID: ", this.docID);
        Router.go('UpdateQuoteData',{_id: this.docId});
    }

Router.route('/quote/:_id', {
  name: 'UpdateQuoteData',
  data: function() { return QuoteData.findOne(this.params._id); }
});

<template name="AddQuoteData">
  <div class="well well-sm">
    {{> quickForm
    collection="QuoteData"
    template="bootstrap3-horizontal"
    label-class="col-xs-3"
    input-col-class="col-xs-8"
    id="AddQuoteDataForm"
    type="method"
    meteormethod="addQuoteData"
    resetOnSuccess=false}}
  </div>
</template>

<template name="UpdateQuoteData">
  <div class="well">
      <h3>RENDERING UpdateQuoteData TEMPLATE</h3>
    {{> quickForm
    collection="QuoteData"
    template="bootstrap3-horizontal"
    label-class="col-sm-3"
    input-col-class="col-sm-8"

    id="UpdateQuoteDataForm"
    type="method-update"
    meteormethod="updateQuoteData"
    doc=this
    buttonContent="Update"}}
  </div>
</template>
```

When I submit the form the client browser redirects to http://localhost:3000/quote/null

In the browser console I get..

```
addQuoteData method - Adding Object {name: "b", email: "a@b", canContact: "No", targetCloud: Array[1], level: "51-100"…}
QuoteData.js:21 currentDocID is..  CqJxB8npwxeYiyKsv
hooks.js:8 running after addhook for AddQuoteDataForm insert! - docID:  undefined
```

Comment: Are you conflating `docId` and `_id`? Are you setting a `docId` in your autoform? If not then the document will get an `_id`